# How to open files in vertical splits by default?

Tags: split

Is there a way to make vim (or nvim) open all new splits vertically by default? There's `splitright` to control which side vertical splits open on, but as far as I can tell there's no built in option to make splits vertical by default. Does anyone know of a workaround? I found one for the help command specifically, but I'm looking for something that will make *all* splits vertical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really an option that does that.

You can accomplish that by using an `autocmd`, more specifically catching the `WinNew` event and moving the newly created window so that it's a vertical one rather than horizontal.

For example:

```
autocmd WinNew * wincmd L
```

(Don't forget to add this to an appropriate `augroup` and clear the `augroup` first, so if you reload your vimrc it won't duplicate the rules.)

Note also that this isn't always the same as using `vertical`, since `wincmd L` will always make the new window the rightmost vertical *top-level* window. It's also somewhat hard to override it (you can use the `:noautocmd` modifier, but that will disable *all* `autocmd`s.)

But perhaps this is close enough to what you're looking for.

Comment: This has gotten me closer to the behavior that I want than any other suggestion I've seen; thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome @MorganMay! Glad I could help. By the phrasing of your question, I felt this might have been what you were after...

Answer (score 8):

`:split`, `:new` and such **are** "horizontal" commands. But they all have "vertical" counterparts: `:vsplit`, `:vnew` etc. Take a habit to choose the right ones.

Also, you're not allowed to redefine Vim builtin commands (except a few starting with a capital letter), but, if you wish, you can redefine key mappings, such as `nnoremap <c-w>n <c-w>v` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible and not all commands that open windows (e.g. `:sp`), have vertical counterparts (e.g. `:vsp`).

So a couple of years ago, I made the [splitvertical](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-mq-patches/blob/master/verstplit) patch, that introduces the 'splitvertical'  option.

Unfortunately, it has never been included.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no option because there’s an specific command: `:vsplit` (`:vs`). It takes a filename as an argument, just as `:sp` does. In fact the option you mentioned, `splitright`,  affects the behaviour of `:vs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<C-W> f` to open the filename under the cursor into a new split. [Its behavior is similar to `:split` followed by `gf`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_f). You can also use `<C-W> <C-F>` for the exact same behavior.

Thus, I propose remapping the second one to a vertical split:

```
nnoremap <C-W><C-F> :vsplit<CR>gf
```

Its behavior will be different than `<C-W> f` if the filename can't be found, as this remapping will still open a new vertical split, while `<C-W> f` won't.